# Dual list drag drop control

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, controls, listbox

Does anyone know of a good .Net2.0+ compatible dual listbox control that either offers dragging and dropping between lists, or simple buttons to move items between lists and also sort the items in a particulr list. This is for a web based app and I would prefer some nice javascript to make this one speedy.

Comment: No answers yet huh? I don't know of anything exactly matching your request either, but you could probably cobble something together with YUI. Check it out if you haven't already.

Comment: Is this how your solution worked? Serializing the order to a hidden field and deserializing on postback to update the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to write my own drag and drop list control for this one using JQuery and JQuery UI. You can try out a sample here: [demo](https://rps.is/dual-list/sample.html). The right side sort list will scroll down if the left list is too long thus making it easier to drag and drop. I still have more testing and a few bug fixes on this one, but it seems to be working pretty well.

Comment: Awesome!  I like the insert-placement like you'd expect from a nice GUI and it works great in Opera.  Kudos!

Comment: The link has gone 404...

Comment: -1 Because the link is still broken after being aware of that a year ago. Posting a code sample here or a screenshot would have been helpful but for now this answer is almost no use to the rest of us.

Comment: I put up a new piece of sample code for the dual list. This definitely isn't production ready and would need to be updated to the latest version of jQuery, but it seems to work fairly well: [http://monkey.ca/dual-list/sample.html](http://monkey.ca/dual-list/sample.html)

Comment: The provided link is still broken.

Comment: I found the old code and re-posted the sample: https://rps.is/dual-list/sample.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852995/whats-this-ui-pattern-called/2853050#2853050) your question?

From that post the infinity links to meadmiracle for a [jQuery implementation](http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBDocumentation.aspx) and a [demo](http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBPlugin.aspx). I personally don't like the horizontal layout of the buttons though although I'm sure that could be fixed pretty easily.

[image: meadmiracle jQuery example]

Also I've found this [jQuery multi selection control](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html) interesting over on the [UX Stack-Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/what-is-the-best-ui-for-multi-select-from-a-list/3419#3419).

[image: jQuery Dropdown Check List]