# What's this UI pattern called?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, yui, terminology

I'm trying to figure out what this sort of thing is called, and eventually how I can create one in a web browser. It looks like this (screenshot of the first app that came to mind):

[image]

The specific component/pattern I'm looking for is the two [list boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_box) ("Included Gear" and "Excluded Gear") that represent inclusion/exclusion of items from a set. I'm not really looking for the WPF name (if there is one) but it might be helpful.

I *am* looking for the name of this thingy, if there is one, and if you really want to make my day, you can point me toward a jQuery or YUI way of making one of these dealies in a browser.

Comment: I am familiar with this construction, but I also don't know its name. I'm just wondering, though - if you're using jQuery, what advantage does this have over a pair of connected sortables? http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/connect-lists.html

Comment: @Stobor: being able to double-click items between lists, (not shown in this example, but is shown in others) being able to select/move multiple items at a time, not forcing user to drag-and-drop. Frankly, the d&d fanciness just isn't terribly appealing here.

Comment: +1 for the heads up about optigear ftw!

Comment: +1 for an interesting and potentially very useful question. A searchable title (good luck) is the only thing lacking

Comment: @Merlyn: thanks :) let me know if you have any staggeringly brilliant ideas for a better title. It was the best I could do.

Comment: see also http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/73852/whats-the-common-name-for-this-gui-elment-left-right-box-assignmentbox-rela

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I don't think there's an "official" name, typically called "dual list" or.. even more commonly known as "the thing where you have two boxes and you can move things in between".

Here's a jQuery Plugin for this: https://github.com/Geodan/DualListBox

Comment: Oh man, does that ever look perfect. A little clunkier than your average jQuery plugin but far better than doing it myself from scratch.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit clunky to get working, but after that I never had to go back to fix it

Comment: "the thing where you have two boxes and you can move things in between". ROTFL!!! true...

Comment: Thanks, Infinity. After checking out all the different options mentioned, I'm going to give the meadmiracle one a shot.

Answer (score 36):

In [Designing Interfaces](http://designinginterfaces.com/), a [UI patterns](http://designinginterfaces.com/firstedition/index.php?page=About_Patterns) collection, [Jenifer Tidwell](http://jtidwell.net/) calls that a ***list builder***. Both ["dual list"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22dual+list%22+user+interface+pattern&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and ["list builder"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22list+builder%22+user+interface+pattern&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) seem to be recognized names for it in both the [academic literature](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.6593) and [industry](http://osdpl.fluidproject.org/designPatterns/List-Builder) [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511484.aspx), even appearing here on SO in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881070/long-check-list-ui-pattern-for-web/883595#883595) on the post *[Long check list ui pattern for web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881070/long-check-list-ui-pattern-for-web)*.

I don't know whether or not there's a packaged jQuery component, but DZone has an article on rolling your own using jQuery: *[An HTML List Builder: A Study in Applying jQuery](http://java.dzone.com/articles/an-html-list-builder)*

I also found a [different *list builder* pattern](http://www.welie.com/patterns/showPattern.php?patternID=list-builder) which takes a very different approach to the same core problem.

The patterns in those and other, similar [design pattern catalogs](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/) may give you inspiration for other ways of attacking the problem, too. I've personally always considered the "dual list" pattern a bit of a hack for which we've had much better alternatives for... decades, now :-)

---

***Update:*** I just stumbled across this pattern also labeled as a ["swaplist"](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/swaplist.html) in [Tklib](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1777) and a ["Disjoint listbox"](http://incrtcl.sourceforge.net/iwidgets/iwidgets/disjointlistbox.html) in the [[incr Widgets]](http://incrtcl.sourceforge.net/iwidgets/) Tk "mega-widget" library. Thus, you will find it in [Perl/Tk](http://www.perltk.org/), [Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), [Ruby/Tk](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_tk.html), and *"anywhere (else) fine (Tk) widgets are sold."*

---

***Update: (2021)*** the [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) React components library calls this pattern a ["transfer list"](https://material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/) or a ["shuttle"](https://material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/). I didn't find a reference to it in the Material Design specification itself, though, so this may be an invention of the component library authors.

Comment: +1 for the formal pattern reference, thanks.

Would you mind giving a couple of examples of the 'much better alternatives'?  I appreciate a multi-select list-box would also meet the requirement, but it can be difficult for the user to maintain a picture of which items are currently selected in a long list when they're not in the visible portion.

Comment: Welie.com calls this pattern the ["Parts Selector"](http://www.welie.com/patterns/showPattern.php?patternID=parts-selector) -- unfortunately the "list builder" pattern mentioned in this answer is a very different solution. Too bad Welie.com calls this different solution "list builder", because I really like that name for the pattern (so I'm going to do with dual-list).

Comment: @ianmayo: I think that might have been a case of me thinking "surely there are better alternatives to this by now?", but I was probably also thinking of direct-manipulation things like D'n'D collection builders, etc. I'd edit that out of the answer, but I keep thinking I'll eventually think of a specific example and want to come back and finish the thought :-)

Answer (score 6):

I heard a vendor refer to them as [slushbuckets](http://wiki.service-now.com/index.php?title=Slushbucket).

Answer (score 6):

It's really a glorified multi select list.  Since there is only 2 states "included" (selected) "excluded" (not selected).  There is a pretty nice multi select widget that splits the selected and not selected items in to 2 columns and lets you drag and drop between then two:

http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

Comment: Wow, that example seemed almost unusable just because it didn't follow the typical left to right ordering. Other than that it looked really pretty ;)

Answer (score 5):

Not that the [Microsoft UXGuide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb328626.aspx) is definitive by any means or as complete as it should be but they refer to this concept as a [**List Builder**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511484.aspx#listBuilders).

[image]

I've recently been searching for examples of this UI concept as well in order to get an idea of the best practice for when to use arrows or labeled buttons and such. The search that has yielded the most examples through Google images has been **dual list ui**.

In terms of a jQuery solution for the second part of your question I think infinity's answer is probably the most appropriate but I just wanted to give you my two cents on what I've found regarding this UI pattern.

Comment: @Matt - np, also don't forget the ux site under the stack exchange that might give you better results for this type of question. http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I asked this question almost a year ago; ux.se didn't exist back then! :)

Comment: @Matt - Good point, note that occasionally they have started migrating questions between these sites. Mainly just wanted to make sure you and others were aware in order to help find relevant content.

Comment: The referenced content was moved and is now here: [List Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742407.aspx). The overall structure of documentation is different so I chose not to modify the post.

Answer (score 3):

I've always thought it was called an **accumulator**, but I had a very hard time finding anything to support that on Google. Here's a mention of it in an [obscure philosophy graduate thesis about UI usability](http://www.isys.ucl.ac.be/bchi/publications/Ph.D.Theses/Florins-PhD2006.pdf).

> Figure 4-1 shows an example of a
>   reorientation rule applied to an
>   accumulator widget (i.e. a component
>   transferring items from the left list
>   of possible values to the right list
>   of accumulated selected items).

[image: Figure 4-1]

And another mention in some [student projects from 1998](https://web.archive.org/web/20010122101100/http://www.cs.nyu.edu:80/ms_students/diam7644/sp98/index.html).

Comment: I quite like this term - because perhaps it isn't 'list items' you want to move around, perhaps its a selection of thumbnails or code snippets, or... many other things.

Answer (score 3):

I have always referred to them as "Shuttle Components" since you are shuttling info back and forth - it seems that this is [somewhat common](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+shuttle+component&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a). Just figured I'd add it to the list of possibilities.

Comment: I only know it as "shuffle box" - never heard "shuttle"

Answer (score 2):

I would think of them as connected sortables in a web context: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples that are not jQuery or YUI but close.  These two examples are from ExtJS; one utilizes two Trees and the other two Data Grids.  Both are pretty slick and might be able to help you with the design ideas.

BTW: I have normally heard them referred to as Dual Lists as well.

[Two Grids](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html)

[Two Trees](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/two-trees.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's often referred to as a "Mover," or "List Mover."

Here are JavaScript and JQuery examples.

http://javascript.internet.com/miscellaneous/move-dual-list.html

http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/move-list.php

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/listbox-select-all-move-left-right-up-down-javascript.html

http://kgaddy.com/jqueryMoverBoxes/

Implementations often enable you to do multi-select and move all the selected items at once.

Another variant is to enable double-click to cause the move.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard control for this. Usually it is implemented with two lists and some buttons to move one or all items from one list to another and vice versa. Instead of a button to move a single item a double click could be used. To move one or more items dag and drop can be employed.

As for the name of th pattern ... I don't really have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a proper name for it but DevX has a page that covers a straight [JavaScript implementation](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/16372/1954) of such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

My colleagues and I have always referred to this as the "two-box select".  Seems to roll off the tongue nicely.

Comment: Interesting, reminds me of Firefighter speak for a "two-box alarm". I agree though it does roll of the tongue.